# closing the gap between two graphs with patchwork

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to close the gap between the two graphs and to make it seem like it is a single graph.

I saw [this solution][1] but it's doesn't work for me.

Thanks in advance

![My plot][2]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)


bp_data=read.csv("./LA metals.csv")
values<- read.csv("metals values.csv")
b = seq(from = 0, to = 226, by = 10)
l = c(0, 226)

year=bp_data$Name=as.factor(bp_data$Name)
bp=ggplot(bp_data,aes(x = Name, y = Pb.Ca)) +
  stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar',width=0.5)+
  stat_summary(fun=mean, geom="point", shape=20, size=3, color="cornflowerblue")+
  geom_boxplot(color = "black", width = 0.5)+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 5.4, size=1,color="red")+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = b, limits = l,expand = c(0, 0))



Pb.lach=subset(values[c(3:4),c(1,6:7)])
Name=Pb.lach$Term=as.factor(Pb.lach$Term)
val=ggplot(Pb.lach,aes(x = Name, y = Pb.Ca))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Pb.Ca-SD.2, ymax=Pb.Ca+SD.2), width=.2)+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = b, limits = l,expand = c(0, 0))
 

bp+val
```

Answer (score 4):

One option to remove the gap between plots when using `patchwork`:

1. Remove the `plot.margin`s from both plots.
2. For the second plot remove all y `axis` elements an set the tick length to zero.

Using `mtcars` as example data:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), hp)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(0, 0, 0, 0, "pt"))

p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), hp)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(0, 0, 0, 0, "pt"),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.line.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.length.y = unit(0, "pt"))

p1 + p2
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!!! it worked!